# What's the difference between "idem" and "ditto"?

Tags: latin, interjections

I understand that in colloquial American English people retort with "ditto" when they mean "likewise", but I don't know that it is a correct use.

I always thought the real meaning was "as I previously wrote/said before", which would make that "right back at you" use incorrect. At the same time, I thought that "idem" would actually be the word to use in that case, use which [the wiktionary seems to back](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idem#Italian).

Anyone able to shed some light into etymology or correct usage?

Answer (score 3):

The formal definition of "ditto" doesn't quite mean "likewise," true, but at least in American English it's a widely accepted slang usage. I wouldn't use it in formal language, but I also wouldn't call it *incorrect* per se.

"Idem," it seems to me, is a much less general term, not to mention a very uncommon one. Wiktionary does list "idem" as a synonym of "ditto" and "likewise," but I think a better synonym of "idem" is "ibid." According to the New Oxford American Dictionary, "idem" is "used in citations to indicate an author or work that has just been mentioned: *Marianne Elliott, Partners in Revolution, 1982; idem, Wolfe Tone, 1989.*" Merriam Webster defines "idem" as "the same as something previously mentioned — used chiefly in bibliographies."

Maybe try "same," as in:

"I am completely addicted to chocolate."

"Same!"

This isn't really any less informal than "ditto," but you might prefer it. I'll add as a caveat that I don't know how regional this usage of "same" is or isn't. (I'm from the San Francisco Bay Area.)

Comment: The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ditto) definition of the 'Amen.' sense of 'Ditto.' does not include even an 'informal' caveat.